# X509certificate2 security warning

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate2

When i'm trying to add a new certificate to the X509Store there's a warning. There are thousands of certificates and the warning window ruins the automation

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
var someCert = new X509Certificate2();
store.Add(someCert);
```

How can i avoid this without changing my **StoreName** and **StoreLocation** settings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you cannot. Dialog popup call is hardcoded in Crypt32.dll.